# Getting null resource from the resolver

Tags: aem, sling

I am getting a Resource object on a component JSP using `resource.getResourceResolver().getResource(path)`
but it is null. I have already made sure that the path exists. It's strange that when I am calling this method on any other component JSP it is working fine. But on the component that I have created, it is null. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have permissions to read the resource. For instance, all resources under `/apps` and `/libs` are unavailable for the `anonymous` user on the publish. You may check the current permissioning for given node in the *Access Control* tab in CRX DE.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. The problem is that the code to fetch Resource resource.getResourceResolver().getResource(path) is fetching null on the component I have created while it is working just fine on another component that exists in the same directory. Do you think it has something to do with my component ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from this brief description. Try posting an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

From the API:

Returns:
The Resource object loaded from the path or null if the path does not resolve to a resource.

[Sling API](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. The problem is that the code to fetch Resource resource.getResourceResolver().getResource(path) is fetching null on the component I have created while it is working just fine on another component that exists in the same directory. Do you think it has something to do with my component ?